# How would I get a substring of svg tag using Regular expression?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, svg, nsregularexpression

I have xml string from svg file as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2626 3807">
 <g>
  <title>BG Layer</title>
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="600" width="300" fill="#bfbfbf" id="svg_26"/>
 </g>
 <g>
</svg>
```

I want to get the rang of follow string using reqular expression.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2626 3807">
```

My code is

```
NSRegularExpression *regularExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<svg([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSRange matchRange = [regularExp rangeOfFirstMatchInString:urlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, urlString.length)];
```

it's not working.

Comment: What about `<svg[^>]*>`?

Comment: yes it did work. Thanks alot. you should put that in the anwers, so that I can vote up.

Comment: could pls tell the reg for viewBox="0 0 2626 3807"

Comment: Are you sure you need regex to do this?  Please see [Don't Parse XML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1366033)

Comment: I am working SVG file. Some of the file has tag for width and height and some file has viewbox. I am trying to change the file tag with viewbox.